# How to extract p-values from BigQuery linear regression

Tags: google-bigquery, linear-regression

I am running a simple linear regression model in Google BigQuery, but when evaluating the model output I cannot seem to find/extract p-values or other information normally outputted from a linear regression model (e.g., confidence intervals). Can anyone advise how to achieve this? I find the output somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately computing p-values, t-values, etc for BigQuery ML models is not currently supported.

Comment: If possible, could you please provide some documentation to support this?

Comment: You can probably try to import the model into python and calculate it there.